# Emberjs Fixture adapter queryFixture not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have been having an issue implementing the queryFixtures function in Emberjs-Data. I have the following code to define the Store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {
        console.log(query);
        console.log(type);
        return fixtures.filter(function(item) {
            for(prop in query) {
                if( item[prop] != query[prop]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
})
});
```

My Model looks like:

```
FireSurveyApp.User = DS.Model.extend({
  userId: DS.attr('number'),
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  FirstName: DS.attr('string'),
  LastName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When i try to get the fixture data out i am using the following code:

```
var returnUser = this.store.find("User",{ username : "Ted"});
```

The function will return undefined, Is there a different way that i should be calling the queryFixtures function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution. Set the store adapter back to DS.FixtureAdapter.

```
adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
```

Implement the queryFixtures Function in the ember-data js file as shown:

```
queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {
var key = Ember.keys(query)[0];
return fixtures.filterBy(key, query[key]);
},
```

After both these steps have been done I was able to query the fixture as shown above with no problem. Hope this helps anyone experiencing the same issue.