# Error when querying for records in ember.js when using FixtureAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a model from another page in the `model()` function of a route. This works fine when I look up the record by ID:

```
self.store.find('thing', 1).then(function(beers) { 
    self.controllerFor('edit').set('title', beers.get('beer'));
});
```

However, when I try to use a query to get this, I get a `Error: Assertion Failed: Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: error` message from line 14261 of ember.js.

Here's the code that causes the issue:

```
self.store.find('thing', { beer: params.beer }).then(function(beers) { 
    self.controllerFor('edit').set('title', beers.objectAt(0).get('beer')); 
});
```

I've ensured that the model has the section property and that params.section is being set properly from the route. What would be causing the error? The problem is demonstrated in [this bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wikayaqupi/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Instead of page.objectAt(0).get('text') , can you try page.get('firstObject').get('text')

Comment: I can't reproduce it see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/waciya/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for the bin! It turns out the my problem was that I was using the FixtureAdapter, which doesn't have an implementation for its queryFixtures function. Question is updated with a bin that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the JavaScript error thrown wasn't very helpful, there actually was this useful message when I checked the console log: `Error while processing route: index" "Assertion Failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store.`

To fix this, I modified the queryFixtures function in ember-data.js based on the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185704/emberjs-fixture-adapter-queryfixture-not-working).